# Developing mySQL query for recurring patients in hospital database

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I'm currently developing an SQL database to manage a Hospital.

The Hospital has tables for doctors, patients, surgeries, diagnostic and analysis appointments, etc.

I would like to create a query for listing/displaying the most recurring patients within the hospital (counting those who keep coming for surgeries, diagnostics or analysis appointments).

I thought of making a VIEW, but haven't managed to get it working, the code will follow below.

I also thought of making it into a query instead, although I am not sure how to proceed. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here follows my attempt.

Thanks in advance,
Best regards.

(The function at hand is the "recurringPatients" one, all the rest can be disregarded when considering the problem).

```
drop trigger despedirMedico;
drop trigger medicoDespedidoNaoFazConsultas;
drop trigger medicoDespedidoNaoFazCirurgias;

drop view melhoresMedicos;
drop view falhasDosMedicos;

drop table pedido cascade constraints;
drop table medicamento cascade constraints;
drop table receita cascade constraints;
drop table consulta cascade constraints;
drop table cirurgia cascade constraints;
drop table medpac cascade constraints;
drop table medico cascade constraints;
drop table especialidade cascade constraints;
drop table analise cascade constraints;
drop table paciente cascade constraints;
drop table pessoa cascade constraints;

create table pessoa (
nif varchar2(15) primary key,
nome varchar2(30) not null,
cod_postal varchar2(10) not null
);

create table paciente (
nif varchar2(15) primary key,
num_utente varchar2(20) unique,
foreign key (nif) references pessoa(nif)
);

create table analise (
id_analise varchar2(15) primary key,
descr_analise varchar2(50) not null,
data_realiz timestamp(0) with local time zone not null,
preco float(2) not null,
nif varchar2(15) not null,
foreign key (nif) references paciente(nif),
check (preco > 0)
);

create table especialidade (
cod_esp varchar2(5) primary key,
nome_esp varchar2(20) not null
);

create table medico (
nif varchar2(15) primary key,
salario float(2) not null,
cod_esp varchar2(5) not null,
despedido integer not null,
foreign key (cod_esp) references especialidade(cod_esp),
check(salario > 0 and despedido in (0, 1))
);

create table medpac (
med_nif varchar2(15) not null,
pac_nif varchar2(15) not null,
check (med_nif != pac_nif),
primary key (med_nif, pac_nif),
foreign key (med_nif) references medico(nif),
foreign key (pac_nif) references paciente(nif)
);

create table cirurgia (
id_cirurgia varchar2(15) primary key,
descr_cirurgia varchar2(20) not null,
num_sala integer not null,
data_realiz timestamp(0) with local time zone not null,
preco float(2) not null,
correu_bem integer not null,
med_nif varchar2(15) not null,
pac_nif varchar2(15) not null,
foreign key (med_nif, pac_nif) references medpac(med_nif, pac_nif),
check (num_sala > 0 and preco > 0 and correu_bem in (0, 1))
);

create table consulta (
id_consulta varchar2(15) primary key,
cod_esp varchar2(5) not null,
descr_consulta varchar2(20) not null,
num_sala integer not null,
data_realiz timestamp(0) with local time zone not null,
preco float(2) not null,
med_nif varchar2(15) not null,
pac_nif varchar2(15) not null,
foreign key (med_nif, pac_nif) references medpac(med_nif, pac_nif),
foreign key (cod_esp) references especialidade(cod_esp),
check (preco > 0)
);

create table receita (
id_receita varchar2(15) primary key,
id_consulta varchar2(15) not null,
foreign key (id_consulta) references consulta(id_consulta)
);

create table medicamento (
id_medicamento varchar(15) primary key,
nome_medicamento varchar2(30) not null
);

create table pedido (
id_receita varchar2(15) not null,
id_medic varchar2(15) not null,
quantidade integer not null,
primary key (id_receita, id_medic),
foreign key (id_receita) references receita(id_receita),
foreign key (id_medic) references medicamento(id_medicamento),
check (quantidade > 0)
);

create or replace view falhasDosMedicos as (
select pessoa.nif as nif, nome, sum(correu_bem) as num_falhas
from pessoa inner join (medico inner join cirurgia on (nif = med_nif)) on (pessoa.nif = medico.nif)
group by pessoa.nif, pessoa.nome
);

create or replace view melhoresMedicos as (
select nif, nome
from falhasDosMedicos
where (num_falhas = (select min(num_falhas) from falhasDosMedicos))
);

create or replace view recurringPatients as (
    select pessoa.nif, nome, count(*) as atendimentos 
    from pessoa inner join (paciente inner join ) on (pessoa.nif = paciente.nif)
);



create or replace trigger medicoDespedidoNaoFazCirurgias
    before insert or update on cirurgia
    for each row
    declare medico_despedido integer;
    begin
        select despedido into medico_despedido
        from medico
        where (medico.nif = :new.med_nif);
        if medico_despedido = 1
            then Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'O médico especificado já não pode exercer funções neste hospital');
        end if;
    end;
/

create or replace trigger medicoDespedidoNaoFazConsultas
    before insert or update on consulta
    for each row
    declare medico_despedido integer;
    begin
        select despedido into medico_despedido
        from medico
        where (medico.nif = :new.med_nif);
        if medico_despedido = 1
            then Raise_Application_Error (-20100, 'O médico especificado já não pode exercer funções neste hospital');
        end if;
    end;
/

create or replace trigger despedirMedico
    after insert or update on cirurgia
    for each row
     declare numf integer;
    begin
        select num_falhas into numf
        from falhasDosMedicos
        where(falhasDosMedicos.nif = :new.med_nif);
         if numf >= 3
            then update medico set despedido = 1;
         end if;
    end;
/
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GMB Let's say a patient P1 came to the hospital  on 15 occasions (2 times for surgeries, 10 times for diagnostic appointments and 3 times for analysis). 
And another, patient, P2, came on 3 occasions (once for a surgery, twice for diagnostic appointments).
I want to display a view that will list, after verifying a conditional statement on the count variable (let's say if count > 5), all the patients that come to the hospital more often (P1, in this case, would make the list and P2 would be disregarded). Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, and consider whether there's an opportunity to simplify it down to just the bare essentials

Comment: And, for the love of humanity, just store a regular integer id for your surrogate primary keys.